# Arranging boys & girls in pairs

Tags: probability, combinatorics

10 girls and 10 boys were randomly arranged in pairs. Find expected value of number of pairs composed of girls solely. My idea for a variable is: 
$X_i -$ i-th girls in a pair with a girl.
but what should i do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of any given girl being paired with a boy is $\frac{10}{19}$.  So the expected number of girls paired with boys is $\frac{100}{19}$.  Thus we expect $\frac{90}{19}$ girls to be paired with girls, but that counts each girl-girl pair twice.

So the expected number of girl-girl pairs is $\frac{45}{19}$.

Comment: I am lost i have received two contradictory answers...

Comment: Actually, I think the answers end up in the same place.  Just different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

What do you do with the expression
$
E(X_1+\cdots+X_{10})
$? Can you calculate it? Can you interpret what it means?

Alternative solution: let $Y_i$ be the indication variable of the event "the $i$th pair only consists of girls". Then calculate $E(Y_1+\cdots Y_{10})$.

Comment: thus could it be like that: $\mathbb{E}X=10P(X_i=1)=10 \frac{9 \choose 1}{19 \choose 1}$?

Comment: That is what I had in mind, yes. So now you know the expected number of girls that have a girl buddy. What does that say about the number of pairs?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Well, say there were four girls who ended up in a pair with another girl. How many all-girl pairs does that make?

Comment: I think, two is the number.

Comment: That's right. And so, since the expected number of girls who is in a pair with another girl is $4.74$, the exact same reasoning gives that the expected number of all-girl pairs is...?

Comment: $4.74/2$? or something else...

Comment: No, not something else. That is correct.